# Is there a way to hide the WFS loading features window by default in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wfs

When adding a WFS layer to QGIS a window pops up showing the progress loading features.

You can hide the window but I believe you have to do this each time you open a project for every WFS layer on your map.

[image: Screenshot of the window]

This function is likely to make QGIS projects difficult to use if you have a lot of WFS layers on the map, say more than 10 or 20.

Is there a way to turn off this window in the advanced settings?

I'm using QGIS version 3.22.